# Definition of algebraic "ring" extension

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Mukai in his book "An introduction to invariants and moduli" uses a concept (first appearing section 2.3 finitely generated rings) which is known to him as *algebraic ring extension* (maybe more precisely it should be called *algebraic domain extension*). Unfortunately he never defines what he means by this notion. For example:

> **Lemma 2.22** Suppose that an integral domain $B$ is algebraic and finitely generated over a subring $A\subset B$. Then there exists a non-zero element $a\in A$ such that $B[a^{-1}]$ is integral over $A[a^{-1}]$.

I did a little bit of digging but I did not come up with a clear cut definition of algebraic *ring* extension anywhere. Algebraic *field* extension on the other hand is very well known. However with a little bit of thought I came with a few possibilities for the definition of algebraic ring extensions, and want to see which one is the true definition:

> **Possibility I:** Let $A\subset B$ be an extension of integral domains. Let $K,L$ be respectively the field of fractions of $A,B$. Then $K\subset L$, an induced field extension. We call the *ring extension* $A\subset B$ *algebraic* if the induced field extension $K\subset L$ is algebraic.

The above possibility yields a weaker version, which turns out to be equivalent to the above:

> **Possibility I':** Let $A\subset B$ be an extension of integral domains. We call this ring extension *algebraic* if every $x\in B$ satisfies a polynomial (not necessarily monomial) equation  $a_0x^d+\cdots+a_d=0$ with $a_0, \cdots, a_d\in A$.

Then comes the last possibility which is based on the following observation:

Suppose $A$ is an integral domain, $K$ its field of fractions and $L/K$ an algebraic field extension. Then we have $A\subset K\subset L$. Every element $x\in L$ satisfies a polynomial equation (is a root of) $a_0x^d+\cdots+a_d=0$
with $a_0, \cdots, a_d\in A$. Define $B$ as the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. Then one checks that $L$ is the field of fractions of $B$.

This might result in a different possibility (in fact in the Lemma above, and as far as I know, whenever Mukai uses algebraic ring extension, the reason he does it is because he needs the above observation to hold):

> **Possibility II:** Let $A\subset B$ be an extension of integral domains. Let $K,L$ be respectively the field of fractions of $A,B$.
>   Then we call the *ring extension* $A\subset B$ *algebraic* if $B$
>   is the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.

Note that this is a stronger version of Possibility I'. This is because the above implies $B$ is integral over $A$. Hence $A\subset B$ is also algebraic in the sense of Possibility I'. Since Possibility I' is equivalent to Possibility I, Possibility II is in fact the strongest definition of them all.

Comment: See this [prior question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/759345/242)

Comment: For example, from Kaplansky's *Commutative Rings*, where R $\subset$  T are integral domains: **Remark.** In saying that T is algebraic over R we mean that every 
element of T satisfies a polynomial equation with coefficients in R, no 
attempt being made to have the highest coefficient 1; this is equivalent 
to saying that the quotient field of T is algebraic over the quotient field of R. 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Io9bo.jpg